# Find and escape names with apostrophe in shell

Tags: shell, escaping

I have a list of usernames like the following:

call StoredProcedure('O'Rielly@ysol-test.net');

call StoredProcedure('Mark@ysol-test.net');

call StoredProcedure('James@ysol-test.net');

As you can see some names have apostrophes in them and some do not.

In Shell, I want to be able to find and escape the second occurrence of an apostrophe on a line IF there are more than 2 occurrences.

Ive managed to remove all occurrences using SED but im drawing a blank here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to be able to find and escape the second occurrence of an apostrophe on a line IF there are more than 2 occurrences.

That's surprisingly simple:

```
sed "/'[^']*'[^']*'/s/'/\\\\'/2"
```

- `/'[^']*'[^']*'/` - if the line matches this regex with three `'`
- `s` - replace

  - `'` - apostrophe
  - `\\\\'` - for `\'`. Note that we are inside double quotes. So first double quotes change `\\\\` into `\\` then sed changes `\\` into `\`.
  - `2` second occurrence only.

Comment: thank you, i knew what needed to be done but my mind was completely drawing a blank on the how part. Also... im really bad at sed :D